# Embedded Twitter Post not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I am trying to embed twitter's [video tweet](https://twitter.com/Ashi_IndiaToday/status/931353265228324864/) in WordPress Post. The embedded tweet isn't showing the video thumbnail in this [post](https://www.themangonews.com/regional/sacred-heart-school-teacher-brutally-canes-student-in-hyderabad/).

I have updated WordPress version 4.9 and am using twentysixteen theme.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Looks like it works for me in Chrome browser.

Comment: Looks like it is browser dependent. Works for me in IE11, Edge, Safari and Opera, but not in Firefox, Chrome and Maxthon.

Comment: It works first a couple of time when we load the website, but not always showing up the embedded video on the website. In mobile device, it will show always but inconsistencies are always with the Desktop or High resolution-ed screens.